# What does "&:" mean in JessRule?

Tags: java, protege, jess, nexpose

I have this JessRule code

```
     (ServiceConfiguration
        (endpoint ?j_endpoint &:(call ?j_advertiserEndpoint equals ?j_endpoint))
        (config ?j_config &:(call ?j_config containsSetting "verbs-count"))
     )
```

Does the code mean that it assigns the return value of (call ?j_advertiserEndpoint equals ?j_endpoint) to j_endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ampersands (&) represent logical "and", while pipes (|) represent logical "or." A colon (:) followed by a function call is a logical expression (constraint) that is true if the function returns the special value TRUE.

The search for endpoint facts succeeds if it has a single field that equals the return value from the call.

No assignment takes place.

Comment: Where do you learn JessRule, I can't find any source

Comment: @AnaMarieDeVera The site originally publishing Jess appears to have closed down. An apparently quite comprehensive secondary source is here: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~sylee/courses/jess/docs/language.html